# Oracle 11g "Duplicate column name" error on view with no duplicate columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Somehow, Oracle 11g thinks there's duplicate column names in my view-creation code:

```
DROP VIEW users_view;
CREATE VIEW users_view AS 
    SELECT * FROM users u
        INNER JOIN states s 
            ON u.state_id = s.state_id
        INNER JOIN accounts a
            ON u.account_id = a.account_id
;
/
```

I run this in SQLDeveloper and get this error message:

```
Error starting at line : 109 in command -
CREATE VIEW users_view AS 
    SELECT * FROM users u
        INNER JOIN states s 
            ON u.state_id = s.state_id
        INNER JOIN accounts a
            ON u.account_id = a.account_id
Error report -
ORA-00957: duplicate column name
00957. 00000 -  "duplicate column name"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any way I can resolve this?

Comment: maybe you need to avoid use "select *" and specify column by column. If you have some duplicate column name, then use an alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, this query has duplicate columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     states s 
     ON u.state_id = s.state_id INNER JOIN
     accounts a
     ON u.account_id = a.account_id
```

Among the duplicates are `u.state_id`, `s.state_id`, `u.account_id`, and `a.account_id` -- the table alias is ignored.

I recommend that you list all the columns that you want from each table.  However, if the duplicates are only the `JOIN` keys, then there is a short-cut -- you can use `USING` instead of `ON`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     states s 
     USING (state_id) INNER JOIN
     accounts a
     USING (account_id)
```

Comment: Nice, is that oracle only syntax?

Comment: Spelling out the column names I wanted to return was the answer.

Comment: @AbBennett . . . No, it is ANSI syntax, but some databases (SQL Server comes to mind) don't support it.